# Fill BD of images only path in Java

Tags: java, mysql

Hi I have a web page in ASP.NET which show a form with the information extracted from an image of one side will be the form and image of the other, have filled the database in Java, but what I need to do 1000 is to insert images and routes of these images are in a local path, really do not know how, I was checking some tutorials but all do with Blob.Yo I just want you when the query is made it look and form across the image.
This is my code in Java to fill the database.

I actually have this

```
public class ImagenesBD {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String ruta = "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Carpeta_imagenes";
    File carpeta = new File(ruta);
    if (carpeta.exists()){
        System.out.println("La carpeta " + ruta + " ya existe");
    }else{
        System.out.println("La carpeta " + ruta + " se ha creado");
        carpeta.mkdir();
    }
    File imagen = new File ("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\descarga.jpg");
    if (imagen.exists()){
        FileReader fr = new FileReader (imagen);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        System.out.println("se ha leido la imagen");
        System.out.println(imagen);
    }else{
        System.out.println("la imagen no existe");
    }
    String origen = "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\descarga.jpg";
    String destino = "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Carpeta_imagenes";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String cadena = destino+"\\"+"descarga-"+i+".jpg";
        System.out.println(cadena);
        File copia = new File(cadena);
        Files.copy(imagen.toPath(), copia.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }

}
 }
```

Although the location of the folder should be in concerning the execution of the program